# Android loading animation before VideoView start

Tags: android, android-videoview

I don't find any solution to show a loading animation (or just an imageView) before a VideoView start to play : during the video is buffering.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to understand you, but I think what you want is an indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear.

My VideoView play a video in streaming. So when I the activity start I only see a black screen while the video is buffering. If you look to YouTube app by instance, there's an animation explaining that the video is loading, and I don't think that it's an inderterminate progress bar.

How could I detect that the video is buffering ?

Thanks

Answer (score 45):

Or you can just use Progress Dialog;

```
public class VideoEkrani extends Activity {

    VideoView ekran;
    String kaynakYolu = "http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
    ProgressDialog progDailog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sayfa_video_goruntule);


        ekran = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewESPU);
        ekran.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        ekran.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(kaynakYolu));
        ekran.requestFocus();
        ekran.start();

        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait ...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

        ekran.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have saved my life!! Thanks a million-trillion times @Amourreux. I know its kind of inappropriate to thank people on stack-overflow, but its also insufficient to let it go without telling people, that if they are facing trouble in VideoView, this one is the solution.! :)

Comment: what if the user seek video, how can you put a progressBar until it stream again ??

Comment: @Mr.G i'm not sure but i thing that event is managed by MediaController. again i am not sure. if i understand your question correctly. if not, it might be good and new question post.

Comment: thanks , ill check it , if not ill put a new quesiton

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found the method `setOnPreparedListener()` on VideoView.

I added a ProgressBar inside my layout, and hide it with the OnPreparedListener

Answer (score 7):

You cant detect the video buffer using `OnBufferingUpdateListener` on `MediaPlayer`. If you use `VideView` set that listener inside `OnPreparedListener`.

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
     mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
         if(percent == 100){
           //video have completed buffering
         }
       }
     });
   }
});
```